# ASP.NET Verbose Model Field Names for CRUD Pages

Tags: asp.net, model

I am trying to build a CRUD page for my model with provided `aspnet-codegenerator razorpage` functionality, and the way the output cshtml page is set up is I have my field names  next to text fields. I would like to make them look like something that would make sense to a user and not developer, that is, add a verbose name. I know Django provides such a functionality, but is there a way to do it in ASP.NET?